# Derived objects in Clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I want to ask what is exactly the derived object in ClearCase and how is work.

Additional i want to ask if there is an other program with the same function, because in Git, MKS or in IBM® Rational Team Concert™ i cannot find something similar, is it obsolete ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite linked to dynamic views, which are very specific to ClearCase and not found in other more recent VCS.

See "[ClearCase Build Concepts](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_build_windows.doc/clearcase_build_concepts.htm)"

> Developers perform builds, along with all other work related to ClearCase, in views. Typically, developers work in separate, private views. Sometimes, a team shares a single view (for example, during a software integration period).
>
> As described in Developing Software, each view provides a complete environment for building software that includes a particular configuration of source versions and a private work area in which you can modify source files, and use build tools to create object modules, executables, and so on.
>
> As a build environment, each view is partially isolated from other views. Building software in one view never disturbs the work in another view, even another build of the same program at the same time. However, when working in a dynamic view, you can examine and benefit from work done previously in another dynamic view. A new build shares files created by previous builds, when appropriate. This sharing saves the time and disk space involved in building new objects that duplicate existing ones.
>
> You can (but need not) determine what other builds have taken place in a directory, across all dynamic views. ClearCase includes tools for listing and comparing past builds.
>
> The key to this scheme is that **the project team's VOBs constitute a globally accessible repository for files created by builds**, in the same way that they provide a repository for the source files that go into builds.
>   **A file produced by a software build is a derived object (DO)**. Associated with each derived object is a configuration record (CR), which `clearmake` or `omake` uses during subsequent builds to determine whether the DO can be reused or shared.

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_build_windows.doc/images/build_scheme.gif]

> A derived object (DO) is a file created in a VOB during a build or build audit with clearmake or omake.
>   Each DO has an associated configuration record (CR), which is the bill of materials for the DO. The CR documents aspects of the build environment, the assembly procedure for a DO, and all the files involved in the creation of the DO.
>
> **The build tool attempts to avoid rebuilding derived objects**.
>
> - If an appropriate derived object exists in the view, clearmake or omake reuses that DO.
> - If there is no appropriate DO in the view, clearmake or omake looks for an existing DO built in another view that can be [winked](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_winkin.htm) in to the current view.
>
> **The search process is called shopping**.

This is relevant for very large C or C++ makefile-based projects.

Comment: Just to add some context and answer -  "is it obsolete ? ", I once worked on a very large application (~ 3M SLOC) which would take 3+ days to compile and link from scratch. Being able to use DO's  "significantly" reduced the time to compile, link. As HW improved and prices dropped, we could eventually build same in a matter of hours from source  on new HW. Changing technologies from monolithic apps to smaller modular services, etc. also reduced the cost benefits ($$ licensing - ++  vs idle devs - --).

Answer (score 1):

I think the TL;DR version of this is:

Derived objects contain information that describes

- What was accessed to build the object, including dependencies that may bot be in your build files.
- Other files created during the build process ("Sibling Derived Objects")
- The commands used to build the object (The "build script") assuming that clearmake, omake, or the ANT listener were used to run the build.

In the case of clearmake and omake, this information is used to avoid rebuilds, potentially speeding builds. The lookup is referred to DO "shopping" and the build avoidance is "winkin."

If you have regulatory or security compliance or needs where this level of auditing is critical, there really isn't anything else that does this.