# MVFS error in a snapshot view

Tags: clearcase

I created a snapshot view using Rational ClearCase explorer.

After creating it, I tried compiling my code and got an MVFS error:

```
Unable to determine if the current working directory is in MVFS - no such device or address
```

When I searched the IBM website for the sake of eliminating this error, I found out that a snapshot view does not use the MVFS.

Why am I getting this error when Snapshot view does not use MVFS?

Comment: What is your OS? What version of ClearCase are you using?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying the most important things !! My OS is Windows 2003 and the Rational clearcase explorer version is 8.0.0.15.

Comment: What is the exact path you are in, and the command you type, when you see that error message?

Comment: The path is **xmalviv_view/NBA_axess_aup2/refsys/aup/aup61** and the command which I give is **clearmake.exe all**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The path is xmalviv_view/NBA_axess_aup2/refsys/aup/aup61

A snapshot view is only accessible through a full local host path:

```
cd C:\path\to\snpashotview
```

[`clearmake`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearmake.htm) is generally linked to and used in dynamic view (see "[Derived objects in Clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35746321/6309)").
Seeing that error message is not a surprise if you use it in a snapshot view and expect certain clearmake features:

> The distinctive features of `clearmake`, such as build auditing, derived object sharing, and build avoidance, are supported in dynamic views only.

Comment: Actually I am creating this view in the **h** drive. Is that the reason I am getting this error? Should I create it in the **c** drive instead to eliminate the error? Instead of clearmake.exe which command do you want me to use for the compiling the code in the snapshot view ? No specific command has been specified in the link which you have given for building the code in a snapshot view.

Comment: By the way I forgot to mention that I am doing all these things in a Windows 2003 **server**.......

Comment: @CodingNinja Sorry for the late answer: ``H:\`` drive is just a `subst` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2324719/6309): if it references a path no ``C:\`` drive, then it still is a snapshot view.

Comment: Hi VonC ! No issues as I was not there in the office for the past 14 hours ! Kindly elaborate on the usage of  `subst` as I am finding it difficult to undersatnd its usage. BTW which command do you want me to use for building my code in the snapshot view?

Comment: @CodingNinja `subst` is just a way to shorten the length of a path used for a snapshot view. Type `subst` in a CMD session to check if ``H:\`` is associated to a path no the ``C:\`` drive. Again, I detail it in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2324719/6309.

Comment: @CodingNinja "Which command do you want me to use for building my code in the snapshot view?": It depends on what you need to build, but if it has a `Makefile`, then a simple `make` should be enough.

Comment: @CodingNinja Again, it depends on what exactly you are building. Is it in C? Java? C#? Javascript?

Comment: it is a C code that I am trying to build. It does have a makefile. The only thing is it is not able to execute it. I think I dont even have permissions to execute it as I am creating the view in the H drive.

Comment: @CodingNinja Then you need to make sure you have the C tool required to build it: ClearCase is just there to get you the code on your machine.

Comment: It does have a makefile. The only thing is it is not able to execute it. I think I dont even have permissions to execute it as I am creating the view in the H drive also the path is too long I guess.

Comment: @CodingNinja Again, type subst to check if H is just a shortcut or not.

Comment: Oh damn it ! I have removed the view in the H drive. Now I am going to create a new snapshot view in the C drive. Should I use the subst command even after I create a snapshot view in the C drive? Please post your next comment as an answer so that this chat does not get too long. I dont have enough reputation to chat.

Comment: No, you don't need subst: you can use directly the path you have chosen for your snapshot view root folder.

Comment: Is using a 'C' drive mandatory for these snapshot views? The process of creating the a snapshot view is going very slow in C drive where as in H drive it is very fast !

Comment: @CodingNinja No, you can use H if H reference an actual disk.

Comment: Please tell me in detail what I have to do to build my C code after I create a snapshot view in the H drive. Earlier you told me that C drive is the drive which is suitable for creating snapshots and now you are saying that it could be created in the H drive also. I am new to clearcase and I am confused a lot regarding this issue.

Comment: @CodingNinja That I don't know. ClearCase is just there to get you the code. How that code builds is entirely specific to the project. It does not depend on ClearCase. As for snapshot view, what I am saying is that they are created on physical disk (``C:\``, ``H:\``, whatever, as long as there is a normal NTFS disk behind that drive letter). ``M:\`` is typically the drive used by ClearCase for dynamic view, using MVFS (Multi-Version FileSystem).

Comment: I do understand what you are telling me (that build is entirely project specific). My problem is **build used to succeed when we had an older version of clearcase but the when that version was upgraded the build started failing. That is the reason I am stressing more on the clearcase features (such as creating views in a C drive for snapshots).**

Comment: @CodingNinja That is not mentioned in your question at all. Did your view changed between your older version of ClearCase and your newer version of ClearCase?

Comment: @CodingNinja Did you understand what I meant regarding snapshot views being created on any NTFS disk (whether or not those disk are called C:\ or H:\ or any other letter except M:\)?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the complete problem earlier ! :) (1) No we never changed the snapshot view between the older and newer version of clearcases. It was being put into the H drive (which is a NTFS drive). (2)Even the paths never changed. (Those long paths which we are giving to access the makefile and build the code) (3) What changed was only the clearcase's version (It was upgraded from some version to 8.0.0.15). ** ONLY AFTER UPGRADING TO THE LATEST VERSION OF CLEARCASE,  THIS PROBLEM HAS ARISED !! HENCE I AM STRESSING MORE ON CLEARCASE RATHER THAN BUILD !  **

Comment: @CodingNinja Got it. I wold try (for testing) to create a new snapshot view, using a similar path as your current snashot view, and using the same config spec.

Comment: So you say something has gone wrong with the **config spec** ?

Comment: @CodingNinja Not necessarely. I suspect the metadata associated with your legacy snapshot view might not be well interpreted by the new ClearCase. In doubt, I would create a brand new one, using the same config spec (so getting the same files) and see if clearmake works better there, in a snapshot view created by CC 8.0.

Comment: Hi VonC ! I even tried creating a new snapshot view using the same config spec, but the error still remains the same. Kindly elaborate on ** Interpretation of metadata by the new ClearCase and ways to eliminate that recognition problem !! **

Comment: @CodingNinja Was you legacy view UCM or base ClearCase (ie, when you do cleartool catcs in your old view, do you see the word "stream" or not? And do you see rules starting with "load" in said legacy view config spec?)

Comment: As I am new to the project I am not so sure about the legacy of older version of the ClearCase.  base ClearCase is the legacy of newer version of the ClearCase .....If you say that the legacy of the older clearcase version should be known, then I will find out.

Comment: @CodingNinja I mean, go the the old view, the one which was working with the old ClearCase, and type: `cleartool catcs`, then look for the word 'Stream' or 'load', and let me know which one you find in the output of that command.

Comment: We no longer work on the older version of the clearcase...it has been completely replaced (upgraded) to newer version 8.0.0.15 where execution of cleartool catcs gives the load word .

Comment: @CodingNinja I understand you no longer work with the older version of ClearCase: the cleartool catcs can be executed with the new CC 8.x. Seeing "load" means your old view was a non-UCM snapshot view indeed.

Comment: @CodingNinja for testing, could you create a similar snapshot view on the C drive (even if it is slow to load) and see if a clearmake works better there?

Comment: Hi VonC , The C drive is not an NTFS drive !. It says that it is just a system drive.

Comment: @CodingNinja Can you ask a new question with all the details we have discussed in those comments, in order for other ClearCase specialists to chime in?

Comment: ok sure . I will definitely make a new question to solve the issue. Shall I delete this question? Please give me some time to frame the complete question.

Comment: @CodingNinja No, you can leave it as it, for context: You can refer to to in your new question.

Comment: The older version we used to use is 8.0.0.7

Comment: @CodingNinja Sure: mention all that in your new question.

Comment: Hi VonC ! I have re-posted the question after framing every sentence. I made sure that I have not omitted even a single point while specifying the issue. I am waiting for your valuable comments to pour in. :)

Comment: @CodingNinja That looks like a more much more complete question, good job! I don't have much more information on that issue at the moment.

Comment: Hi VonC ! I have compiled my code with some errors in the **R drive** which is an NTFS drive. This time there was no MVFS error.The errors are like **Build script failed for lib/powerpc/release/libmemcmds.a**. Can you give me some more suggestions so that I can build my code successfully.

Comment: @CodingNinja That would be best as a new question, for others to contribute. No need to go on indefinitely in those comments ;)

Answer (score 1):

Recently there was a development in the solution of this issue !! We escalated this issue to IBM with the help of our client. They suggested us to use Dynamic views and we used them. To our surprise it was working fine and we are able to generate the executables. But the fact still remains that we are not able to use snapshot views !!

**NOTE:** This comment is just to share my knowledge and experience regarding this issue. :)