# MVFS error in a snapshot view after upgradation of ClearCase

Tags: build-process, clearcase

I created a snapshot view using Rational ClearCase explorer.

After creating it, I set the config specs, environmental variables and later tried compiling my code and got an MVFS error which says:

**Unable to determine if the current working directory is in MVFS - no such device or address**

When I searched the IBM website for the sake of eliminating this error, I found out that a snapshot view does not use the MVFS !

Why am I getting this error when Snapshot view does not use MVFS?

**When this issue got triggered:** Actually in our project we were using a ClearCase (8.0.0.7 version). We never had problems when we tried to build our code on the 8.0.0.7 version. It was only after upgrading this version to 8.0.0.15 that the build issue has arisen. The legacy of both old and new ClearCases are baseClearcase

**Some more specifications regarding the issue:**
The server which we are using is a Windows 2003 server. I am creating a snapshot view in H drive (NTFS drive) as C drive is not available for use in our project, cleaning the previously built files by running the shell script clean_view.sh and then compiling our C code with the ClearCase command `clearmake.exe all`. Previously we used to follow the same procedure where build used to succeed, but now the same has become an issue.

This question is an extension to the question which I have asked previously. I am re-posting this question as a whole thing again in order to give more clarity about the issue and also for more number of ClearCase experts to chime-in. Kindly do not treat this as a duplicate one or force close it as my issue has not yet been resolved. Also please note that this is the first time I am working with ClearCase.

**LINK FOR THE PREVIOUS QUESTION:** [MVFS error in a snapshot view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414703/mvfs-error-in-a-snapshot-view/37415969?noredirect=1#comment62416038_37415969)

Answer (score 1):

Recently there was a development in the solution of this issue !! We escalated this issue to IBM with the help of our client. They suggested us to use Dynamic views and we used them. To our surprise it was working fine and we are able to generate the executables. But the fact still remains that we are not able to use snapshot views !!

NOTE: This comment is just to share my knowledge and experience regarding this issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

While a snapshot view isn't in the MVFS, *clearmake* has MVFS-specific functionality for build auditing.

You mentioned that the "H" drive contained the snapshot view, is H:

1. A local or network drive?
2. A drive letter created via SUBST? In this case, is the parent drive local?
3. Do builds in dynamic views still work?
4. Does the C drive *exist*? Is it remapped in a Terminal Server/Citrix environment?

A caveat: Windows Server 2003 is nearly a year past **MICROSOFT'S** end of extended support. I would recommend updating the server environment as soon as possible.

Truthfully, issues where a process fails, and the ONLY change is the ClearCase version are usually best handled by contacting IBM instead of using this venue. Not trying to shill or anything, but if it's a clearmake bug, it has to go there anyway...

Additional questions:
If the C: drive is inaccessible on the system, which is what "can't even get the properties" in the comment seems to infer, where is the OS installed? Where does %SYSTEMROOT% point?

If it worked on a different drive, what's different between those 2 drives (H: Failed and R: worked)

Comment: 1 -> H drive is an NTFS drive as indicated in the question and is local to the windows 2003 server. 2 -> It is not created via SUBST  3-> We never tried creating a dynamic view so far 4 -> Yes the C drive exists in our server, but it is not an NTFS drive. We are not even able to view the properties of that drive and when ever we select that drive (with a single click), the computer says that it is a system folder. (displayed to the left of the window in windows 2003)

Comment: Hi Brian ! I have compiled my code with some errors in the **R drive** which is also an NTFS drive. This time there was no MVFS error.The errors are like **Build script failed for  lib/powerpc/release/libmemcmds.a**. Can you give me some more suggestions so that I can build my code successfully.

Comment: @CodingNinja Please enter a separate question on that.

Comment: Sure dude ! I will frame the question and post it.  :)