# Build issue after the upgradation of clearcase from 8.0.0.7 to 8.0.0.15

Tags: makefile, build-process, clearcase

**When this issue got triggered:** In our project we have been using ClearCase (8.0.0.7 version). We never had problems when we tried to build our code on the 8.0.0.7 version. It was only after upgrading this version to 8.0.0.15 that the build issue has arisen. The legacy of both old and new ClearCases are baseClearcase.

**NOTE:** We are using Windows 2003 server.

**Specifications about the drives we are using in our project:**
We are given three drives (namely `H`, `R` and `M` drives). `H` and `R` drives are NTFS drives where as `M` is an MVFS drive. Usage of `C` drive is completely out of scope as we are not given access to this drive. We generally create Snapshot views as creation of dynamic views is not encouraged in our project.

**What I did previously:** I compiled my code in the `H` drive (We used to use this drive even before the upgradation of clearcase) and got an MVFS error !! Since I did not get satisfactory answers when I posted this question: [MVFS error in a snapshot view after upgradation of ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461248/mvfs-error-in-a-snapshot-view-after-upgradation-of-clearcase), I started some vague trials on `R` drive (which is also an NTFS drive) and tried to build my code on it. Luckily it was compiling but with some errors which say:

**** Error code 1

clearmake.exe: Error: Build script failed for **/so/and/so/path.a**
 (There are five such errors)

and we also have

**** Error code 1

clearmake.exe: Error: Build script failed for mods (There were two such errors)

**1-->** Is it the makefile which is causing this trouble? If yes, Is it due to upgradation of clearcase?

**2-->** Is the `R` drive suitable for the creation of snapshot views and should I continue with it?

Can someone tell me the complete solution for this compilation failure?

Comment: Whenever I see mvfs error on a snapshot view, the first thing I test is a complete uninstall of ClearCase, followed by a reboot and a full re-installation of ClearCase. Then I check if the issue persists.

Comment: Hi VonC ! I forgot to mention that it is the Client that takes good care of installing, uninstalling and ugradation procedures of clearcase. We do not have any rights to do those things !

Comment: Sure, you would need to request said un-install, re-installation. My point is the upgrade process might have glitches.

Comment: Ok Sure ! I will request for that, but is there anything which you can comment on changing the makefile? We have already raised a dispute and they asked us to run the clearcase doctor. They told us that there are no issues as far as the clearcase environment is concerned and that we have to change our makefile and its dependencies.

Comment: I don't have much experience on the makefile front, but I would try the usual debug tricks: try and simplify the makefile, see if any .a file trigger the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the clearmake output using the -dv  options to provide more debugging statements on the exact command that failed?

Comment: The compiler says: Target "so/and/so/path.o" file does not correspond to MVFS object. Configuration look up disabled for target "so/and/so/path.o". No candidate in current view for the "so/and/so/path.o". Build for some static libraries (.a files) have also failed.

Comment: Prior to the upgrade, were you using snapshot or dynamic views to perform the builds?
The reason I ask is because path names between snapshot and dynamic views will be different when building.
In your first description, you specified that the path name with the error was: 

 /so/and/so/path.a 

which would signify a possible path in a dynamic view.

Comment: even before the upgradation, we were using snapshot views....we never changed those views .

Comment: Do you have any idea where "so/and/so/path.o" is relative to where the build script starts?  Is it possible that there is a variable that needs to be set that might be a prefix to "so/and/so/path.o"?
Without seeing more of the clearmake -dv build output and the makefile that is being used, it's really hard to say what specifically could be wrong.